# Symmetric Multi-Key Decryption

Tags: encryption

Is there an encryption decryption scheme in which a group of people are all given different keys, and of which each key can decrypt a file. (I’m not talking about a scenario where a file is encrypted with a single symmetric key, and then the symmetric key is separately encrypted with each individuals public key.)

I’ve read articles about broadcast encryption and multi-trapdoors but I'm unsure if any of these would match the correct scheme so I’m looking for.

Comment: Why does each key have to be different?  What would go wrong if every user had the same key?

Comment: Pretend we had to revoke access to one user. Since we used the same key for $$n$$ users, we now have to change the keys for $$n - 1$$ users. That means each revoke operation is linear instead of constant.

Comment: @SlackOverflow I think you need to clarify the question a bit. Because suppose I say yes there is a method in which multiple keys can decrypt the same data. But now you're adding the condition that it's possible to revoke a key. And I'm assuming from what you said, that you want to be able to revoke the key without having to modify the encrypted data in any way. All this needs to be stated clearly in the question: what are the assumptions, security goals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- encrypt the file with an aes key.
- encrypt that key using ECIES with the sum of two EC public keys, the user's EC public key and your key server's EC public key.  hash(ephpriv * sumkey) == aes. perform one encryption per user.
- when decrypting, key server replies with partial decryptions for a specific key (KS private * ephemeral public).  the sum of their hash(Upriv*ephpub + KSpriv*ephpub) == aes
- when the user goes to decrypt, they need to request the other part of their the partial decryption by signing a posk challenge
- revocation means the server will no longer hand over the part of the key the user needs
- key server has no ability to decrypt.  it can only revoke or grant.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use any special asymmetric construct. Just give the group keys and encrypt the file with a unique random key and than encrypt the file key many times using the keys of the permitted users.

You can give each user multiple keys some of them shared by relevant groups. To prevent encrypting a file with too many keys. These can even be done ad-hoc, assuming groups repeat themselves. you can create a group key encrypt it with the keys of the members and reuse it if you want to give that group access to another resource later.

Comment: How would encrypting the file key multiple times allow any one of the generated keys to decrypt the file?

Comment: you encrypt it once with each of keys, so anyone holding any of those keys can decrypt the file key and decrypt the file.

Comment: But how can I make it such that each key is different?

Comment: All keys should be chosen at random from a secure random number generator. Obviously no two keys chosen this way with sufficient length will be the same.

Comment: The OP specifically rules out encrypting the key with individual keys: *"I’m not talking about a scenario where a file is encrypted with a single symmetric key, and then the symmetric key is separately encrypted with each individuals public key"*.

Comment: My answer does not suggest using any assymetric public/private key at all. Ans is not excluded in the question. It is far more efficient.

Comment: Not the point, either has the same issue.